# How to send a discord embed with one image in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

Rather than just sending an image, I want my discord bot to use Discord embed and have an image attached to it, however, when trying to use set_image and sending a new embed to discord no output is provided. I have a file named output.png in my project directory and I just want to see if I can use it within an embed. Here is some test code I used:

```
@client.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='test',colour=discord.Colour.dark_orange())
    embed.set_image('output.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed,file='output.png')
```

Why does this not produce an embed on discord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `embed.set_image` method only accepts an URL of an image, and the `file` kwarg of the `send` method needs to be a [File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File) object, so if you want to send a locally saved image, you need to send it as a file along with the embed, then set the embed image using the `attachment://image.png` URL; the `image.png` can be changed.

```py
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="output.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://output.png")
await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

See the [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image)